# openldap / slapd return the error : "daemon: listen(ldap://my.server1.org, 5) failed errno=98 (Address already in use)"

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

I am trying to set up a master master replication between two openldap servers. To do so, the first steps make me configure theses two files :

- `/etc/hosts`, need to contain the DNS of the baseDN of the servers (itself and the second server) :

```
192.168.150.1 my.server1.org
192.168.150.2 my.server2.org
```

- `/etc/default/slapd`, need to contain the server own FQDN to match the future serverID to the URI  :

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldap://my.server1.org"
```

After configuring the SLAPD_SERVICES variable and restarting the slapd service, I get the following error : `daemon: listen(ldap://my.server1.org, 5) failed errno=98 (address already un use)`.
Note : The service is active (not in a failed state)

All LDAP commands ("ldapsearch -x" for exemple) return the same error : `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

I tried finding the cause by listing all processus running on the server that are using the address `my.server1.org` :

```
lsof -i |grep my.server1.org
nmdb  377 root  25u IPv4 17535    0t0 UDP my.server1.org:netbios-ns
nmdb  377 root  27u IPv4 17537    0t0 UDP my.server1.org:netbios-dgm
```

Note : Killing the PID of netbios didn't solve the problem

As you can see, there is no second slapd/openldap service already running.

I couldn't find a solution by myself or on the internet so I am posting my problem here.

Edit 1 : After the request of @naxto asenjo, here is the result of the command `ss --listening --processes --numeric |egrep "389|636"` :

```
Netid  State  Recv-Q  Send-Q    Local Address:Port                            Peer Address:Port
u_str  LISTEN 0       128       /run/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc 14758   users:(("containerd",pid=389, fd=6)) *O
u_str  LISTEN 0       128       /run/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc 14758   users:(("containerd",pid=389, fd=7)) *O
```

Edit 2 : I tried to change the value in SLAPD_SERVICES and /etc/hosts to a new FQDN I never used (the ldap database is still my.server1.org). After restarting slapd, I get the same error, "address already in use" (for the new FQDN). The /etc/hosts and the SLAPD_SERVICES seems to encounter a conflict ? If I dont edit the /etc/hosts file I get the error "temporary failure in name resolution".

Comment: try running ss --listening --numeric --processes and see if slapd is still running on one of the default ports (389/636)

Comment: slapd is not running, I tried to grep 389, 636 and slapd with ss. The service enter in an active exited state just after the modification of the SLAPD_SERVICES variable.

Comment: something must be listening on the port, post the ouput of ss --listening --numeric --processes | egrep "389|636

Comment: I edited my first post to add the result. After stopping docker and containerd services, the error still remain (I restarted slapd)

Comment: ah, in docker, we had missed that. So now you need to explain the networking setup, but this does not look like a 'professional production environment', rather a test rig, am I correct?

Comment: Yes it's a test rig, and it's not in a docker container i just had the service running along openldap (sorry for the confusion). The network setup is two computers linked to a switch, each computer having one network interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after some time away from the project.

In my SLAPD_SERVICES variable, there was two FQDN addresses used : `ldap:///` and `ldap://my.server1.org/` both using the `:389` port.

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldap://my.server1.org"
```

If you want to resolve the confict, you can remove one of the adresses or change the port of one of them.

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap://:3389/ ldapi:/// ldap://my.server1.org"
or 
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldapi:/// ldap://my.server1.org"
```